# What is this <lt-mirror> html tag?

Tags: html, dom, textarea, custom-element

To make the question short, I was playing with the `dom`, I created a `text-area` and noticed that an element tagged `lt-mirror` was generated whenever the user type something. The new element is placed just before the `text-area`. Couldn't find any documentation about it across the web ?

[image]

Comment: It meets the naming convention of a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) but there's no enough information in your question to say what it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `lt-mirror` tag was generated by an extension called `LanguageTool`, which target the `text-area`s and check for writing errors.

Answer (score 1):

Did some research about this and found something! Okay, so the person who wrote this probably did something called [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements). Rather than having nested, verbose elements for a page feature, you could use a custom element to make it more comprehensive and most importantly reusable!

You can create a custom element made with your classes, own methods, and properties, etc, and use it with the built-in HTML elements.

You can find more info on it here:

https://javascript.info/custom-elements

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I knew what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's some kind of a [custom element](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements).